# Stream based on condition

Tags: flutter, dart

Here the stream is called from 5 places on same screen for different source id like,

```
  final _orderDetailAryFetcher = PublishSubject<OrderDetailAryModel>();
  Stream<OrderDetailAryModel> get getOrderDetailAry$ => _orderDetailAryFetcher.stream;

  StreamBuilder<OrderAryModel>(
      stream: orderAryBloc.getOrderAry$,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
     // return widget 
    })
```

Now i want to sink the data for each stream seperately,

```
    _orderRefresher.listen((int source_id) async {
      print('Enter refresh order detail');
      orderModel = await _repository.fetchOrder(source_id);/// fetch data from Live url
      _orderDetailAryFetcher.add(orderModel);  /// sending data to stream
    }
```

Is that possible to add any where condition in broadcast stream,

Comment: *"Is that possible to add any where condition in broadcast stream"* - you mean `Stream.where` method? if so, yes, you can call that method on any `Stream`

Comment: i mean, i need to send the stream value only for 3 streamBuilder block instead of sending the value to all the streamBuilder